# How to edit lightning-textarea programatically in Lightning

Tags: javascript, frontend, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I'm trying to find a way to modify the value of my lightning-textarea.

Not the variable that holds the value internally.

Things like `document.getElementById('textarea').value = 'value';` are not working.

My Textarea:

```
<lightning-textarea id="textarea" type="text" label="Enter some text" onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-textarea>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, clicking the item changes its content. The [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property or the [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method can be used to change the content of the element.

```js
let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
let textarea2 = document.getElementById("textarea2");

/* Clicking on the item fires the following event. */
textarea.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  textarea.innerHTML = "Clicked First Element";
});

/* Clicking on the item fires the following event. */
function clickEvent() { 
  try {  
    this.textarea2.innerHTML = "Clicked Second Element"; 
  }
  catch(error) { 
    console.log(error); 
  } 
}
```

```css
#textarea, #textarea2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- First Element -->
<br><lightning-textarea id="textarea" type="text" label="Enter some text">First</lightning-textarea><br><br><br>

<!-- Second Element -->
<lightning-textarea id="textarea2" type="text" label="Enter some text" onclick="clickEvent()">Second</lightning-textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you but didn't work. I'm trying to modify the inner.HTML using a button and I got this error TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') when I try the following code:

function() {
          try{
            textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
            this.textarea.innerHTML = 'asd';
          }catch(error){
              console.log(error);
          }        
      }

Comment: There could be several reasons for this. First, this can be a problem if an element does not contain the id value "textarea". Second, this issue occurs if the definition in <script> is defined before the <body> tag.

Comment: I'm not even sure if document.getElementById works on lightning to be honest.
It's lightning for Salesforce, the id is there and I'm not sure what else I could check.
Thanks a lot for answer.